# How can I upgrade to Windows 10, but keep windows 7 in a dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a laptop running windows 7 and dual booting to some other operating systems as well (linux and windows 10 TP) with the windows 7 bootloader on the MBR, which points to a grub bootloader as well for linux systems.

My question is this: I really like windows 7, but I would like to upgrade to windows 10. I want to keep windows 7 for compatibility and familiarity, but add a windows 10 installation in my dual booting setup. The problem is that it needs to be an upgrade so the install is free, but I want to keep my windows 7 installation.

How can I achive this? Could I do something like cloning the windows 7 partition and then upgrading one of the clones to windows 10?

Comment: You can try [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-multiple-operating-system-multiboot)

Comment: actually, after further research, I figured out that files on the new partition will still have the filepath to the old partition, which would cause problems when trying to upgrade

Comment: Upgrade will consume the W7 product key into W10, so it will not work anymore for W7.

Comment: Well, how lucky am I: I just found a hard drive lying around with windows 7 on it! Now I can use the product key to install another copy of windows 7 on my computer and upgrade <em>it<em> to windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am dual booting. My Win7 partition is still activated. Probably can't use the product code for a new install tho. There's always Loader by Daz. Their fault for getting rid of WMC.

Comment: Well, how lucky am I: I just found a hard drive lying around with windows 7 on it! Now I can use the product key to install another copy of windows 7 on my computer and upgrade <em>it<em> to windows 10